unable to read the path environment variables in nsis
have to get the path environment variables to notepad using nsis script. but i was getting an empty string with the following code
Section
Readregstr $0 HKLM "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" "Path"
MessageBox MB_OK "test data path: $0"
SectionEnd

I tried with Readenvstr command, but I didn't got the fruitful result.

What happens if you change "Path" to "PATHEXT" for example?

I was getting an output as .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

The Path string is probably too long for NSIS.

Why do you need to read %path%?

Nsis was not recognizing the innosetup created environment variables, while running the installer, NSIS removing the variables which were created by inno installer, So we need to read the environment variables to notepad then using EnvVar we can add into the environement variables.

i have develop the batch script to get the path environment variables to txt file & run the batch script through nsis compiler. using the following code
@echo off
set "output_file=%Temp%\path.txt"
set "path_variable=%PATH%"
echo %path_variable% > "%output_file%"

i have developed the batch script to get the path environment variables to txt file with the following code. Save & run the batch script through nsis Script
batch code here
@echo off
set "output_file=%Temp%\path.txt"
set "path_variable=%PATH%"
echo %path_variable% > "%output_file%"


NSIS variables have a string length limit and it is therefore not safe to modify the %path% environment.
Use the EnVar plug-in if you need to modify %path%.
